# Possibility of implementing drag and drop out from a Chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I am developing a Chrome application that currently resembles a File Manager in its UI. I would like for users to be able to drag and drop "files" both into and *out of* the app, for example, to and from their native file managers.

Does this seem impossible, therefore should I be looking for other user interface options?

I have looked into this question: [Drag out files from browser using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920131/drag-out-files-from-browser-using-javascript) but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work on ChromeOS, the platform I am developing for.

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystemProvider ? This doesn't do what you want, but can make your files appear in the standard file manager.

Comment: Also, can you show your non-working code based on that question? I'm curious how you set up URLs.